# Cannot read property 'sort' of null

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have one template for the grid which I used in two places and grids have a different id's of course.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Equipment)

        .Name(string.Format("equipmentGridReview-{0}", DateTime.Now.Ticks))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity).Title("Qty");
            columns.Bound(c => c.ItemName).Title("Item / Billing Code");
            columns.Bound(c => c.ItemId).Title("Item#");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Disposition).Title("Disposition");
            columns.Bound(c => c.InvLoc).Title("Inv Loc");
            columns.Bound(c => c.EqLoc).Title("Eq Loc");
            columns.Bound(c => c.UnitPrice).Title("Unit Price").Format("{0:c}");
            columns.Bound(c => c.Completed).Title("Completed");
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Events(e => e.DataBound("someModule.onDataBoundToGrid"))
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .Selectable()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .ServerOperation(false)
      )
)
```

Here is my js module

```
function getEquipmentGrids() {
        var grids = [];

        $.each($("[id|='equipmentGridReview']"), function(idx, element) {
            grids.push($(element).data("kendoGrid"));
        });

        return grids;
    }

    function onDataBoundToGrid() {
            setCommonDateSource(this);
        }

    function setCommonDateSource(newGrid) {
            $.each(getEquipmentGrids(), function(idx, grid) {
                if (grid !== newGrid && grid.dataSource !== newGrid.dataSource) {
                    newGrid.setDataSource(grid.dataSource);
                }
            });
        }
```

And when I switching between I get an error. First Array(1) I get when I first upload tab first time, second [init, init] I get when I switching between tabs.
[image]

Comment: Are you calling setDataSource from inside a DataBound handler? Why?

Comment: @GaloisGirl how should I call DataBound?

Comment: why do you want to call dataBound? It's an event that Kendo throws, for example when the dataSource has loaded. 
You don't need to do anything special for two components to share a dataSource: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datasource/shared-datasource

Comment: @GaloisGirl it can be root cause?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: @GaloisGirl post an answer so OP can accepts it.

Comment: Done! @stas-zgurskiy , will you do the honors?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are setting the dataSource of the second grid in the first's [`dataBound`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/databound) event. This could lead to some unintended behavior.

The good news is you don't need to do anything special for two components to share a dataSource. As you can see on the example at https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datasource/shared-datasource , a grid and an AutoComplete simply are passed the same dataSource, and it just works. Both will dynamically reflect any changes made to the data. The same will work for two grids, or any two widgets that have linear data.